# PL/SQL - Member Function: Link directly to object without parameters

Tags: oracle-12c, plsql

I want a table generated from a table function in oracle.

Like this:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CUSTOMERS                                                          |
+----+-------+------------+-------------+---------------+------------+
| ID | FIRST |    LAST    | LOCATION_ID | CREATION_DATE | FULL_YEARS |
+----+-------+------------+-------------+---------------+------------+
|  1 | Max   | Mustermann |          54 | 2017-10-05    |          0 |
|  2 | Hans  | Dimitry    |          87 | 2016-12-26    |          1 |
|  3 | Olga  | Trausch    |          71 | 2015-06-02    |          3 |
+----+-------+------------+-------------+---------------+------------+
```

But I want that the column `FULL_YEARS` is a member function of my object customer.

So I implement my customer object as

```
CREATE TYPE "CUSTOMER" AS OBJECT (
    customer_id           NUMBER,
    customer_firstname    VARCHAR2,
    customer_lastname     VARCHAR2,
    customer_location_id  NUMBER,
    creation_date         DATE,
    MEMBER FUNCTION "FULL_YEARS"(in_date DATE) RETURN NUMBER
);
/
```

My customer object body

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
TYPE BODY CUSTOMER AS

  MEMBER FUNCTION "FULL_YEARS"(in_date DATE) RETURN NUMBER AS
    v_years NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    SELECT FLOOR(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, in_date)/12) INTO v_years
    FROM dual;
    RETURN v_years;
  END "FULL_YEARS";
END;
/
```

As example I declared an anonymous plsql block for testing.

```
DECLARE
  v_customer CUSTOMER;
BEGIN
  v_customer := CUSTOMER(2001, 'Hugo', 'McKinnock', 16, SYSDATE - INTERVAL '18' YEAR);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_customer.FULL_YEARS(v_customer.CREATION_DATE));
END;
/
```

But, how can I directly access in my member function of the column `creation_date` from my customer object. I don't want the parameter `in_date` of my member function.

I want only a call like this for example

```
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_customer.FULL_YEARS());
```

Volker

Comment: Are you wanting a `PIPELINED TABLE FUNCTION` or a `VIEW`/`TABLE` that looks like your results based on a real `TABLE`/`OBJECT TABLE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget my comment.  I was thinking of something else.

Your question is really about "How do I access the `MEMBER` attributes from within a `MEMBER` function?".

In this case, you use the keyword `SELF` as the current instance's name.

Spec

```
CREATE TYPE "CUSTOMER" AS OBJECT (
    customer_id           NUMBER,
    customer_firstname    VARCHAR2(30),
    customer_lastname     VARCHAR2(30),
    customer_location_id  NUMBER,
    creation_date         DATE,
    MEMBER FUNCTION "FULL_YEARS" RETURN NUMBER
);
/
```

Body

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
TYPE BODY CUSTOMER AS

  MEMBER FUNCTION "FULL_YEARS" RETURN NUMBER
  as
     v_years  NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    -- don't do the SELECT INTO FROM DUAL thing.  that is just ugly code.
    v_years := FLOOR(MONTHS_BETWEEN( sysdate, self.creation_date)/12);

    RETURN v_years;
  END "FULL_YEARS";
END;
/
```

Comment: Tanks, this was the solution, but I use now the member function from the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Why define a parameter if you don't want one?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
TYPE BODY CUSTOMER AS

  MEMBER FUNCTION "FULL_YEARS" RETURN NUMBER AS
  BEGIN
    return FLOOR(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, creation_date)/12);
  END "FULL_YEARS";
END;
```